# JS exit a .map() function

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm using a map function to iterate and array, and I want to stop going trough elements inside a map function once a condition has been met.

Is there a way to do so ?

Ex :

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
arr.map((el,index)=>{
  console.log("Element : ",el)
  if(el > 5){
    //Stop the map function and proceed to the next operation
    //like goto line 11 so skip going trough the map anymore
    console.log("Stop")
  }
})

console.log("Sucess!")
```

So in this example I just want to stop the map once the element inside it, has a value bigger than 5.
Is there a way to do this with map, or I should find another solution ?

Why map ? 
-Seems like an intresting solution, and I was wondering if it's possible to use in y case

Comment: Don't use a `map` "sort of like a `for` function". Use a loop if you want to be able to stop it.

Comment: what is **goto:11**? btw why `map`? you don't use the result of it ...?

Comment: Nina goto:11 is a function that older languages used in order to skip a piece of code and go to a certain line of code. In this case 11.
If I remember right one of such languages is assembler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not looking for [`.map`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/map) function, but you need to use [`.some`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/some) or [`.find`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/find)

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
arr.some((el,index)=>{
  console.log("Element : ",el)
  if(el > 5){
    //Stop the map function and proceed to the next operation
    //like goto:11
    console.log("Stop")
    return true // stop the iteration of the first "truty" value
  }
  return false
})

console.log("Sucess!")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `for...of` loop, if you don't need the index:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for (const el of arr) {
  console.log("Element : ",el)
  if(el > 5){
    //Stop the map function and proceed to the next operation
    //like goto:11
   console.log("Stop")
   break;
  }
}

console.log("Sucess!")
```

---

> Why map ? -Seems like an intresting solution, and I was wondering if it's possible to use in y case

You can also use a screwdriver with a thick handle to drive in a nail, but it's still the wrong tool for the job ;)

The only way to stop iteration with `.map` would be to throw an exception. You could do something like this:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var sentinel = {};

try {
  arr.map((el,index)=>{
    console.log("Element : ",el)
    if(el > 5){
      //Stop the map function and proceed to the next operation
      //like goto line 11 so skip going trough the map anymore
      console.log("Stop")
      throw sentinel;
    }
  })
} catch(e) {
  if (e !== sentinel) throw e;
}

console.log("Sucess!")
```

But that isn't better in any way.