# How to render three dots in custom pagination in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have looked everywhere, watched videos and still couldn't get the logic behind adding ellipsis in pagination.

I have created this component `Pagination` (please note this is just a sample component to demonstrate my question)

```js
export const Pagination (props) {
const {maxPages, pageNumber} = props

const totalPageNumbers = []

for(let i = 1; i<= maxPages; i++){
totalPageNumbers.push(i)
} 

return (
<div>
<button disabled={pageNumber === 1}>prev</button>

{
totalPageNumbers.map(item, i) => (
<button onClick={() => someFunction()}> {item} </button>)
}
<button disabled={pageNumber === maxPages}>prev</button>
</div>

)}
```

- `totalPageNumbers` is an array of the total pages
- `maxPages` is a string of the total number
- `pageNumber` is the current page

I would like to show something like this if total pages are 5 or more
**1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 5**

if less than 5, it should be
**1, 2, 3, 4**

Right now everything works fine, but all pages are listed due to the map method above, so if I have 100, it will list 100. I would like to limit that number so it's cleaner.
ellipsis no need to be clickable as long as they look like the example above, I will be super happy. Thanks a lot in advance!

Please help me with this logic, I have been stuck at this for the last 5 hours :(

Comment: Don't use `map`, use `some` or a traditional `for` or `forEach` loop as you'll want to break the loop if you have more than 4 values in the array. On each iteration, use an `if` statement to see if the value is greater than 4, if so, add the button with the ellipsis and the final button with the last element of the array and break out of the loop. Here's an example using `some` : [js-exit-a-some-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193124/js-exit-a-map-function)

Comment: Thanks @RyanWilson I will try to do that. quick question, will the arrows navigation still work when doing it this way?  Also, by `value` are you referring to the total pages or current page?

Comment: I'm referring to the current value of the array at the index of that iteration `totalPageNumbers` is just an array of integers, as to your first question, "will the arrows navigation still work?", I am unclear as to what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks again! @RyanWilson I will give it a go and see if I could put it together. 
before the first and after the last numbers I have arrows for user to move between pages, was wondering if I should change the logic for that one as well. It seems like I will have to do that.

Comment: You should be able to see enough from the answer using `some` on the post I linked above to get you moving in the right direction. And you're welcome. :)